# How to correctly process lifecycle of fragment if app is being killed in background?

Tags: android, kotlin, architecture

```
class MyFragment : BaseFragment {
private lateinit var myPresenter: Contract.MyPresenter
override lateinit var adapter: MyAdapter

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    myPresenter.view = this

    adapter = MyAdapter(
            myPresenter,
            this,
            this
    )
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
}
```

I've structured this type of classes in alot of places in my application. I found out that users get alot of crashes and they're usually `UninitializedPropertyAccessException`. Before you say, that I should make my variable nullable, I think the problem is bigger.

This works fine if u do simple testing - open app and test. Well, if u open the same fragment, press home, and then kill the application process and later on try to re-open the application, it gives error to `lateinit` variables. How should we by-pass this error? I use MVP and MVVM in my applications, so it means that it's crucial to save `Presenters` or `ViewModels` with it's data, because, when process is killed, the data is lost and later on when user tries to interact with application - if the variable is set to lateinit - we get an error. If we set it to be nullable, we won't get the error, but still, we will have unexpected app behaviour. We do not want that...

What's the correct way (examples would be great) to save all UI related things (recyclerviews, adapter instances ect..) **WITH** ViewModel / Presenter instances?

Comment: Sounds like a race condition or an incorrect handling of the activity/fragment lifecycle. Impossible to answer without an SSCCE.

Comment: Can you post **logcat** error for that exception also? @PeteWonder

Comment: i always try to avoid `lateinit`, is it possible to use `by lazy { }` instead of it?

Comment: Try moving your `adapter` initialization to fragments `onCreate` method, and add `recyclerView.adapter = null` in `onViewDestroyed`.

Comment: @m0skit0 What additional information do you need? I am willing to provide it.

Comment: http://sscce.org/